# How to set operation.url programatically in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have an app that retrieves data from an XML file on a server. I know how to set the initial link to the data but I would like this to be able to changed based on the user's setting. How to I update the retrieve data service url in runtime.
I am using the latest version of Flex with Flash builder 4.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you share some of your code with us?  Basically, you just change the URL in ActionScript before calling the service. I believe 'send' method calls the remote service.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to the HTTPService:

```
<mxHTTPService id="service" url="default.php" other="attributes"/>
```

Now you can access the `HTTPService` object using its id from a function:

```
this.service.url = "the_new_url.php";
```